# SimpleDateFormat assertion error

Tags: java, date, junit, simpledateformat

I write this code and I am comparing these two dates, but I get an extra -4:00, I am not sure where it is coming from as I specify that I want yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss which ends at the seconds, so I do not know how to get rid of the -4:00.

```
   @Test
   public void testOrder5() throws Exception {
      Phone input = new DefaultPhone();
      SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = new Date();
      input.setCreatedDate(date);
      Phoneobj output = Book.change(input);
      assertThat(output.getCreatedDate(), is(sf.format(date)));
   }
```

Error is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "2013-10-09T14:27:10"
     got: "2013-10-09T14:27:10-04:00"

    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:780)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:738)
    at ca.on.oicr.DtosTest.testOrder5(DtosTest.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

So I am not sure where the -4:00 comes from or how to get rid of it

```
public class Defaultphone implements Phone{
private Date createdDate;

@Override public Date getCreatedDate()
{
    return createdDate;
}

@Override public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate)
{
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
}
```

then my change method consists of

```
public static PhoneObj change(Order from) {
     PhoneObj phoneobj = new OrderDto();
    if (from.getCreatedDate() != null) {
             phoneobj.setCreatedDate(dateTimeFormatter.print(from.getCreatedDate().getTime()));
          }
return phoneobj;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `DefaultPhone` class?

Comment: -4:00 is added when you have XXXX at the end of your date pattern http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The code you've shown us won't compile if `is()` is `CoreMatchers.is()`. `getCreatedDate()` returns a `Date`, while `sf.format(date)` returns a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your pattern in yout test:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

With this pattern you will get the same format used in `PhoneObj` class.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like output.getCreatedDate()  is returning "2013-10-09T14:27:10-04:00".
I am sure if you debug output object of the line --> Phoneobj output = Book.change(input); 
you will know the reason.

Please share the change Book.change(input), if you are unable to find.

Comment: Check DateTimeFormatter. ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME  ISO Local Date and Time '2011-12-03T10:15:30'
ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME  Date Time with Offset 2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'

Answer (score 0):

Below link will give you dateTimeFormatter predefined formatter: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html